# What is the exact meaning of the candlestick chart on the network download of performance monitor of the chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm watching Network performance on the chrome devtool.

[image]

I notice that I don't know the exact meaning of the **chandlestick chart** on it. I've searched the document pointing it out, but I didn't find it.

[image]

My question is following:

1. What is indicated by the **leading thin line**?
2. What is indicated by the continuing **fat line with light color**?
3. What is indicated by the continuing **fat line with dark color**?
4. What is indicated by the continuing **thin line at the end**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the document here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/reference/#network

> - The left line is everything up to the Connection Start group of events, inclusive. In other words, it's everything before Request Sent, exclusive.
> - The light portion of the bar is Request Sent and Waiting (TTFB).
> - The dark portion of the bar is Content Download.
> - The right line is essentially time spent waiting for the main thread. This is not represented in the Timing tab.